# Partial Sums of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis

It does not want to plot anything? Please, help me understand why. Thank you

```
    f = x - Pi
    p = Pi
    s[n_ , x_ ] := (1/2)*Integrate[ f , {x, -p, p} ]*(1/p) + 
    Sum[  (1/p)*Integrate[f*Cos (k*x) , {x, -p, p}]*Sin (k*x) + (1/p)*
    Integrate[f*Sin (k*x) , {x, -p, p}]*Sin (k*x) , {k, 1, n} ]

    partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}];
    Plot[partialsums, {x, -4, 4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in *Mathematica* get square brackets (i.e. `Sin[x]`), not round brackets.

```
f = x - Pi
p = Pi
s[n_, x_] := (1/2)*Integrate[f, {x, -p, p}]*(1/p) + 
 Sum[(1/p)*Integrate[f*Cos [k*x], {x, -p, p}]*Sin [k*x] + (1/p)*
 Integrate[f*Sin [k*x], {x, -p, p}]*Sin [k*x], {k, 1, n}]

partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}];
Plot[partialsums, {x, -4, 4}]
```

> `-Pi +x`
>
> `Pi`
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica has `FourierTrigSeries` for this.

```
f = x - Pi;
partialsums = FourierTrigSeries[f, x, #] & /@ Range[5];
% // Column
```

[image]

```
Plot[partialsums, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Although interesting this doesn't really address the question as to why no plot was being generated.